# Developing SerialPort Sniffer for Win7 64

Tags: c#, windows, serial-port

I want to develop an app that's able to print all of the data exchanged on a COM port (both ways) without blocking the port, so that other(s) app(s) can use it normally.

After some research I've found DataReceivedEvent, but I think that you've to be the owner of the port in order to use it. What I need it's something like that, but for data received and sended, without owning the port.

Is there a way?

Comment: Do you want to intercept the communication of all programs(and even drivers) or only the communication of some select programs? If it's only some programs you can inject an unmanaged dll into them which intercepts the API they use to communicate with the COM port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hardware splitter will be the easiest solution most likely.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915904/listening-to-serial-com-ports-that-are-in-use) post for addition details.

Answer (score 0):

If you're making a tool, do existing tools not work?

This has been a life saver for me in the past:  http://www.serial-port-monitor.com/